# Need to add string with \ in it to database

Tags: vb.net, escaping, db2, character

I have a string that is read from an excel file.  String is ¬©K!n?8)©}gH"$.F!r'&(®

I keep getting the following error.  When running the insert statement
ERROR [42601] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT] SQL0007N  The character "\" following "  K!n?8) }gH""$.F!r'" is not valid.  SQLSTATE=42601

How do I do this insert with the \ character in the string?  The Character causing the problem might also be the &.

Its a DB2 Database

Thanks

Comment: How do you do the insert, from a cmd window? Check if you need to prevent string from being evaluated by the shell (or whatever it is called in windows). Something like db2 "insert into ...."

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which interface you are sending the insert statement.

In my experience, it is most probably the typewriter single quote character (') which makes the problem.

```
INSERT INTO TEMP.CHAR_TEST 
VALUES ('¬©K!n?8)©}gH"$.F!r''&(®');
```

works fine for me, but notice that I have changed ' to '' (insert another single quote after the existing one).